# How to create DOM element for each object's property variation in an object array?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm a newbie at angularjs and facing a problem.
I'm using an angular calendar (not a creation of mine).
Passing an object array (events) is mandatory for using it's directive in my code.
In templates of this plugin I can "consume" this array of object.

My issue is located here.

The array (eventArray) is composed of object like this one:

```
currentEvent = {
            _id:           bookingArray[i]._id,
            private:       bookingArray[i].private,
            space:         space_name,
            user:          user,
            isOwnBook:     $scope.connected_user._id === user._id, 
            title:         resource_title,
            startTime:     new Date( bookingArray[i].ts_start),
            endTime:       new Date( bookingArray[i].ts_end),
            allDay:        false,
            deleted:       false,
        };
```

Let's say I log each currentEvent.title in the array, console would be like this:

```
RoomA RoomB RoomC RoomA RoomB RoomZ ...
```

I want to create a div each time the currentEvent.title is different.

```
<span ng-repeat="currentEvent in dt.eventArray">{{currentEvent.title}}</span>
```

This previous code should print only:

```
RoomA RoomB RoomC RoomZ
```

How should I proceed in order to obtain this behavior ?

Best regards !

Answer (score 0):

I manage to find out a solution.

You need to install angular-filter first.

Then the code in the template is like this:

```
<span ng-repeat="(key, value) in dt.eventArray | groupBy: 'title'">{{key}}</span>
```

And finally you get as many span as title variation